# Error while running ESLint: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: reactjs, react-native, atom-editor

Hi have recently started a new react native project, however, when i open up my project on atom, i get the above eslint error on every single js file.  I've have opened up my past projects and i dont seem to have that error.  I am not aware that anything has changed.  Can anybody lend a hand?

I am using node version 10.16.3 if that helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might add a picture of the error

Answer (score 7):

I went to `node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-octal-escape.js` and replaced the line in the screen shot with:

```
/^(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?\\([0-3][0-7]{1,2}|[4-7][0-7]|[1-7])/u
```